# "invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment" when trying to summarize

Tags: r

I'm trying to summarize some grouped data and have the following code:

```
yearly.users <- group_by(df, Year)

yearly.users <- summarise(yearly.users,
                         total.users <- sum(participants),
                         mean.users <- mean(participants))
```

This actually works the first time I pass through it. But if I try to change the parameters in the summarize variable, I get:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
```

Don't know how to interpret this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are overwriting yearly.users from the first statement. When you do the first summarise, it loses the structure of the `group_by` needed to do the next one. Change name of the output from summarize to something else.

Comment: i get that error when using `<-` in the `summarise()`. try using `=` instead of `<-` inside the `summarise()` call.

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer that's exactly what it turned out to be. feel free to post as an answer and i'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is stemming from the use of `<-` in `summarise()`.

The operation will work the first time, but with some side-effects that cause the error.  When using `<-` we assign the results both to global and the resulting `data.frame` (see the `ls()` output).  We also create some weird variable names.  If you clear out your environment each time before running these commands you won't get the error (but definitely not the safest thing to do).  Using `=` for defining values in `summarise()` will get the desired behavior without these side-effects.

#### using `<-`

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 <- group_by(mtcars, gear)
df_1 <- summarise(df_1,
                  total.wt <- sum(wt),
                  mean.wt  <- mean(wt))
ls()
# [1] "df_1"     "mean.wt"  "total.wt"
names(df_1)
# [1] "gear"                "total.wt <- sum(wt)" "mean.wt <- mean(wt)"

#running the above code will now give the below error if we dont run rm(list=ls()) first
#Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
#   invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
```

#### using `=`

```
rm(list=ls())
df_2 <- group_by(mtcars, gear)
df_2 <- summarise(df_2,
                  total.wt = sum(wt),
                  mean.wt  = mean(wt))
ls()
# [1] "df_2"
names(df_2)
# [1] "gear"     "total.wt" "mean.wt"
```